# Label angle with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am able to draw a nice right triangle with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (0,0)  -- (4,0) node[midway,below]{$f$} -- (4,2) node[midway,right]{$\frac{x}{2}$}-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I want to label the left angle of the triangle and I am stuck on how to do this.

Comment: The question is "how to label a vertice" and  it's more complicated to label an angle !

Comment: @Altermundus: So something like http://www.tpub.com/math1/20.htm57.gif, especially the arrows that point to the start/end of the angle, is not easy doable?

Comment: Yes it's possible but not with the same facility ! :)

Comment: @Altermundus: Could you maybe elaborate this a bite more? I am new to tikz.

Comment: @Flow Without the arrows, it's simple. You can clip the triangle and draw a circle with center A. If you know the angle, it's also simple, you can draw an arc (look at my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20833/how-to-put-a-mark-on-an-arc-tikz-decoration) but If you don't know the value of the angle, you need to calculate this value and then you need to draw the arc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My answer shows how to label the vertex and the angle. The macro `tikzAngleOfLine`is not optimized

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
  \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(25:3)$);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(100:5)$);
    \draw (A) node[left]{$A$} -- (B) node[right]{$B$}node[midway,below]{$c$} -- (C)node[above]{$C$}node[midway,above]{$a$} -- (A)node[midway,left]{$b$};

    \tikzAngleOfLine(A)(B){\AngleStart}
    \tikzAngleOfLine(A)(C){\AngleEnd}
    \draw[red,<->] (A)+(\AngleStart:2cm) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:2 cm);
    \node[circle,fill=green] at ($(A)+({(\AngleStart+\AngleEnd)/2}:1 cm)$) {$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 54):

Here is a solution using TikZ 3.0:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
  (3,-1) coordinate (a) node[right] {a}
  -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {b}
  -- (2,2) coordinate (c) node[above right] {c}
  pic["$\alpha$",draw=orange,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! The future's looking pretty bright!

Comment: This might not work when the language is set to something other than English. (Didn't work for me in Swedish.)

Comment: To fix the language/babel problem, put `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` in the preamble (See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw/).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add a line where you set the angle style (color, eccentricity, radius) globally?

Comment: Where can I find documentation on `\pic`?

Comment: @Eric [Here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=252) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=[tikz-pgf]+pic).

Comment: I know this answer missed the pary by ~2 years, but it should be the accepted answer by now.

Comment: How can I have the name of the angle be inside the angle instead of outside?

Comment: @rensemil Try with `angle eccentricity` below 1.

Answer (score 9):

I've built on the excellent answer from Alain Matthes above and defined a more direct macro. I've also included an example of its use case.

```
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}                               
  \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%                                            
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%                                                 
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%                                             
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}                                               
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%                                        
  }                                                                            
\newcommand{\tikzMarkAngle}[3]{                                                
\tikzAngleOfLine#1#2{\AngleStart}                                              
\tikzAngleOfLine#1#3{\AngleEnd}                                                
\draw #1+(\AngleStart:0.15cm) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:0.15cm);              
}                                                                              

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line width=1pt]                                    
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);                                                    
  \coordinate (C) at (1,0);                                                    
  \coordinate (A) at (0.5,1.5);                                                
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;                                            
  \node [below left]  at (B) {B};                                              
  \node [below right] at (C) {C};                                              
  \node [above]       at (A) {A};                                              
  \coordinate (D) at (barycentric cs:A=0.5 ,C=0.5);                            
  \node [above right] at (D) {D};                                              
  \draw (B) -- (D);                                                            

  \tikzAngleOfLine(A)(C){\AngleStart}                                          
  \tikzAngleOfLine(A)(B){\AngleEnd}                                            
   \draw (A)+(\AngleStart:0.15cm) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:0.15cm);          

  \tikzMarkAngle{(C)}{(B)}{(A)}                                                
  \tikzMarkAngle{(D)}{(A)}{(B)}                                                
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here's [an example use](https://cl.ly/image/0k3a2j322A0H) of the macro.

[image: an example use]

---

I've also included a slightly more involved example below.

[image: another example use]

```
\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
  \def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
  }
\newcommand{\tikzMarkAngle}[4][0.15cm]{
\tikzAngleOfLine#2#3{\AngleStart}
\tikzAngleOfLine#2#4{\AngleEnd}
\draw[<->] #2+(\AngleStart:#1) arc (\AngleStart:\AngleEnd:#1);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,line width=1pt]
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (0.5,1.5);
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
  \node [below left]  at (B) {B}; 
  \node [below right] at (C) {C}; 
  \node [above]       at (A) {A};
  \coordinate (D) at (barycentric cs:A=0.5 ,C=0.5);
  \coordinate (E) at (barycentric cs:A=0.40 ,B=0.60);
  \node [above right] at (D) {D};
  \node [above left] at (E) {E};
  \draw (B) -- (D);
  \draw (C) -- (E);
  \draw (E) -- (D);

  \tikzMarkAngle{(A)}{(B)}{(C)}

  \node at ($(A)+(-90:0.23)$) {$20^\circ$};
  \tikzMarkAngle{(B)}{(D)}{(C)}
  \node at ($(B)+(25:0.23)$) {$60^\circ$};
  \tikzMarkAngle{(C)}{(B)}{(E)}
  \node at ($(C)+(155:0.23)$) {$50^\circ$};

  \begin{scope}[color=orange]
  \tikzMarkAngle{(D)}{(E)}{(B)}
  \node at ($(D)+(-20:0.15)$) {?=$30^\circ$};
  \end{scope}

  \tikzMarkAngle{(B)}{(A)}{(D)}
  \node at ($(B)+(55:0.23)$) {$20^\circ$};
  \tikzMarkAngle{(C)}{(E)}{(D)}
  \node at ($(C)+(120:0.23)$) {$30^\circ$};

  \coordinate (F) at (barycentric cs:A=0.50 ,B=0.50);
  \node [above left] at (F) {F};
  \draw (F) -- (D);
  \draw (C) -- (F);

  \coordinate (G) at (intersection of D--B and C--F);
  \node [above] at (G) {G};

 \draw (E) -- (G);
 \begin{scope}[color=blue]
   \tikzMarkAngle{(G)}{(F)}{(E)}
   \node at ($(G)+(145:0.20)$) {$40^\circ$};
   \tikzMarkAngle[0.07cm]{(F)}{(E)}{(G)}
   \node at ($(F)+(-175:0.10)$) {$40^\circ$};
   \tikzMarkAngle{(D)}{(A)}{(F)}
   \node at ($(D)+(135:0.22)$) {$80^\circ$};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have searched for many solutions. Finally, no one is satisfactory.

**Solution 1:** 
as shown in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle), use

```
\tkzMarkAngle and \tkzLabelAngle
```

Problem: can't draw an arrow on the arc.

**Solution 2:**
as show in [the same place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle), use

```
\begin{scope}
  \path[clip] (A) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
  \draw [red, fill=red!20] (A) circle (10pt);
\end{scope}
```

Problem: can't draw an arrow on the arc.

**Solution 3:**
the solution in the accepted answer might be complicated for a beginner. And I tried the code, it seems the direction of the arc is not what I expected.

==================================================

**My solution:**
Of course there are many other good solutions. Regarding the problem I am interested in, I came up with a simple solution. I believe many people already know about this. Just post it here for a memo.

```
%Requires \usetikzlibrary{calc} in the preamble
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (B) at (2.345,-1.234);
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (-2.1,3.2);
    \draw [densely dotted, thick] (B)--(A)--(C);
    \draw (A) node[below] {$A$};
    \draw (B) node[below] {$B$};
    \draw (C) node[below left] {$C$};
    % label the angle subtended at p1 by p2 and p3
    \def\angleRadius{30pt}
    % draw the arc
    \draw[red,->,thick] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C), 
        \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
        ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2:\angleRadius);
    % draw the label
    \draw[red] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C), 
         \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
         (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2:\angleRadius) node[above] {$\alpha$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Result:**

[image]

We can use the following code to label the angle which is larger than 180.

```
\def\angleRadius{30pt}
\draw[red,->,thick] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C), \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
    ($(\p1)!\angleRadius!(\p2)$) arc (\n1:\n2-360:\angleRadius);
\draw[red] let \p1=(A), \p2=(B), \p3=(C), \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)}, \n2={atan2(\x3-\x1,\y3-\y1)} in
    (\p1)+(\n1/2+\n2/2+180:\angleRadius) node[below] {$\alpha$};
```

The result is:

[image]

> Features of the solution:
>
> 1. Simple. Simply input the three points that determine the angle.
> 2. the arc is generated by arc command. Can set the arrow of the arc and of course other properties.
> 3. Require \usetikzlibrary{calc}, but no \usepackage{tkz-euclide}.

Comment: You are missing the angle label. Also the problems that you have given are also solvable but still this is also nice.

Comment: @percusse: I have added the label. (I don't know how to integrate the label and arc under one \draw command.) BTW, thanks for editing my answer. Based on your version, I revised it a little bit. I still prefer to introduce \p1,\p2,\p3 instead of only \p1 and \p2 because if I have other three points, I can simply put them in the p1,p2,p3 places, and need not to modify any other things.

Comment: Although this topic is quite old, but I want to correct wrong comment in the answer by Shiyu. More precisely, in Solution 1 he said \tkzMarkAngle can't draw an arrow on the arc. However, tkz-euclide can draw an arrow on the arc, for example, \tkzMarkAngle[size=.5,arrows=->](A,B,C)

Comment: `\tkzMarkAngle` CAN draw an arrow on the arc! (See: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134617/101831](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134617/101831))

Answer (score 4):

You can insert a node at the start of the triangle, at `(0,0)`, and put a label to the left of it with `node[left]{$A$}`. A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (0,0) node[left]{$A$}  -- (4,0) node[midway,below]{$f$} -- (4,2) node[midway,right]{$\frac{x}{2}$}-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't draw the arc that the other answers do, but that wasn't really necessary in my case.

Answer (score 2):

With [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
% triangle
\tzcoors(0,0)(A){$A$}[180](4,0)(B){$B$}[-45](4,2)(C){$C$}[45];
\tzpolygon(A){$f$}[b](B){$\frac x2$}[r](C){\scshape hypotenuse}[sloped,a](A);
% angle marks
\tzrightanglemark(A)(B)(C){90\textdegree}
\tzanglemark(A)(C)(B){$\theta$}
\tzanglemark(C)(A)(B){$\alpha$}
\tzanglemark'[->,red](C)(A)(B){$\beta$}[pos=1.2](20pt)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Since `tzplot` package contains `\AddToHook`, which was added in the LaTeX version 2020-10-01, I have to update my Tex in order to make it compile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 'basic' `tikz` solution with `calc` library also:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(25:3)$);
        \coordinate (C) at ($(A)+(100:5)$);
        \draw (A) node[left]{$A$} -- (B) node[right]{$B$}node[midway,below]{$c$} -- (C)node[above]{$C$}node[midway,above]{$a$} -- (A)node[midway,left]{$b$};
        \draw[red,<->] ($(A)+(25:1)$) arc(25:100:1) node[midway,circle,fill=green] () {$\alpha$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

His output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. However, I wonder why is there a `()` in `node[midway,circle,fill=green] ()`?

Comment: @Flow No problem. You can avoid the (). I published my solution because is a lot simpler with reference to others. For drawing the angle and its label.