# Best way to denote an angle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the best and simplest way to denote an angle, with an arc and a label telling its name? I wish to be able to control (obviously) the vertices on which the angle lays, the name of the angle and also control the radius of the little arc and whether it should fill the whole part-of-a-circle shape in color.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle/

Comment: I just had a look, and all solutions seem so difficult to tweak with ... Is there no other way?

Comment: I wouldn't say `tkz-euclide`s way is difficult to change ... All the parameters you mention are easy to modify.

Comment: I didn't want to use that because as it is said there, the documentation is in French ... Anyway looks like I have no choice. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation is in French, but there are many examples to look at, so one can figure out a lot from looking at those. (All the French I "know" comes from the words being similar to words in English.)

Comment: It would be helpful to see how you are drawing the angles, and perhaps a way you would like to be able to specify them in the form of a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). If the syntax you want to label the angles is not compilable you can comment that out.  Otherwise it is difficult to see what parts you think are difficult to tweak.

Comment: What details do you want to provide to get angle? Is it something like "you give 3 points it will draw the angle and the label."
 ?

Comment: What about just using some nodes ? Like this     \draw[<->] (0,0) to [bend right]  (1,1) node[left,pos=0.5]{\small$\alpha$}; You calculate the position on a line using (...!...!...) and thats it. Not an exact arc but fair enough for a figure

Answer (score 23):

I just have a look to this question and related ones but I don't see anywhere my solution to mark an angle *when you don't know its measure* (maybe I haven't read all the post about the topic...).

So here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$x$] (X) at (6,1);
\coordinate[label=above left:$y$] (Y) at (3,5);

\draw[thick] (X) -- (A) -- (Y);

% Mark the angle XAY
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (A) -- (X) -- (Y);
\fill[red, opacity=0.5, draw=black] (A) circle (5mm);
\node at ($(A)+(30:7mm)$) {$\theta$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I draw a full circle and I hide the bad part of it by clipping with a path built with the three points which define the angle. It seems so easy that it might be a bad way to do it but it works pretty well. Here I put manually the angle measure to place `\theta` but it could be automated surely.

Please, feel free to comment it if you think there are some situations where it doesn't work!

[image: Mark an angle]

Comment: This solution looks smart but it could break in the (perhaps unreasonable) case that the triangle Axy is too small to contain all of the angle mark.

Comment: I find it a nice solution! But, I think that because the way clipping works the filling of the (clipped) circle **overlaps** the edges of the angle. I could not find a way to solve this issue with this approach.

Comment: is there any way to make arc's filling transparent and leaving circle visible

Comment: @Dror You could solve your problem by placing the scope and angle definition before drawing the sides of the angle, then the sides will cover the angle fill.

Answer (score 22):

Another example with `TikZ` only . The line important is `\draw [color=black](a)+(10:1.2) node[rotate=0] {$\beta$};`  the label for the angle is placed with the help of the center and this center is translated `(a)+(10:1.2)`  .

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\coordinate (o) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=150:$A$](a) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=0:$B$](b) at (6,0);
\coordinate[label=90:$C$] (c) at (4,5);
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\node(c1) at (o)[draw,circle through=(a)] {};
\coordinate[label=90:$D$] (d) at (intersection 1 of c1 and a--c);
\coordinate[label=80:$E$] (e) at (intersection 1 of c1 and b--c);
\coordinate[label=60:$F$] (f) at (intersection  of a--e and b--d);
\coordinate[label=-90:$H$] (h) at ($(a)!(c)!(b)$);
\fill[red] let \p1=(f),\p2=(h) in (\x2,\y1) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue] (c) -- ($(a)!(c)!(b)$);
\draw [blue,very thick](b) +(142:.8cm) arc (142:180:.8cm);
\draw [color=black](b)+(160:1) node[rotate=0] {$\alpha$};
\draw [green!50!black,very thick](a) +(0:.8cm) arc (0:21:.8cm);
\draw [color=black](a)+(10:1.2) node[rotate=0] {$\beta$};
\draw [red!50!black,very thick](a) +(21:.8cm) arc (21:53:.8cm);
\draw [color=black](a)+(32:1.1) node[rotate=0] {$\gamma$};
\draw [red!50!black,very thick](b) +(110:.8cm) arc (110:142:.8cm);
\draw [color=black](b)+(128:1) node[rotate=0] {$\gamma$};
\draw [orange,very thick](c) +(-70:.8cm) arc (-70:-127:.8cm);
\draw [color=black](c)+(-100:1.2) node[rotate=0] {$\delta$};
\draw [orange,very thick](f) +(143:.8cm) arc (143:203:.8cm);
\draw [orange,very thick](f) +(24:.6cm) arc (24:-38:.6cm);
\draw (a) -- (e);
\draw (d) -- (b);
\draw[anchor=base,color=blue] (h.center)  ++(.3,0)  -- ++(0,0.3) -- ++(-0.3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But that means I have to know the angles, don't I? Isn't it possible to define a macro or something which gets five parameters - F,A,H, some radius and `\beta`, and it would draw the angle? Maybe it is possible using trigonometry? I'll be glad for any help, at least syntax-speaking.

Comment: In this case, you can try `tkz-euclide` or you can find in some answers how to calculate the angle of a line like AF and you can create a personal macro.

Comment: @Dave did you ever manage this?

Comment: how do i change length of the circle?

Answer (score 15):

I took the PolGab's code and changed it a little:

1. Put an optional argument to change the color
2. Change order of points to name the angle (usually in angle ABC, B is the origin...)
3. Automate the position of the label.

[image: marking angles]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections} 

\newcommand\markangle[6][red]{% [color] {X} {origin} {Y} {mark} {radius}
  % filled circle: red by default
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (#2) -- (#3) -- (#4);
    \fill[color=#1,fill opacity=0.5,draw=#1,name path global=circle]
    (#3) circle (#6mm);
  \end{scope}
  % middle calculation
  \path[name path=line one] (#3) -- (#2);
  \path[name path=line two] (#3) -- (#4);
  \path[%
  name intersections={of=line one and circle, by={inter one}},
  name intersections={of=line two and circle, by={inter two}}
  ] (inter one) -- (inter two) coordinate[pos=.5] (middle);
  % bissectrice definition
  \path[%
  name path=bissectrice
  ] (#3) -- (barycentric cs:#3=-1,middle=1.2);
  % put mark
  \path[
  name intersections={of=bissectrice and circle, by={middleArc}}
  ] (#3) -- (middleArc) node[pos=1.3] {#5};
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$B$] (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (5,5);

\draw[thick] (B) -- (A) -- (C) -- cycle;

\markangle{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}{5}
\markangle[blue]{B}{A}{C}{$\alpha$}{6}
\markangle[green]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}{12}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It will be great if we could pass the radius of the mark as an optional argument also (for instance 5mm by default). Thus, we could use either `\markangle{A}{B}{C}` if we want to use default values for color and mark radius or `\markangle[blue, 10]{A}{B}{C}` if we don't. But I think it is impossible because a `\newcommand` just takes *one* optional argument, right?

Answer (score 8):

(*Edit: recent version of Tikz requires `name path global` instead of `name path`.*)

Here is a complement to sylcha's answer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections} 

\newcommand\markangle[6]{% origin X Y radius radiusmark mark
  % fill red circle
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (#1) -- (#2) -- (#3);
    \fill[color=red,fill opacity=0.5,draw=red,name path global=circle]
    (#1) circle (#4);
  \end{scope}
  % middle calculation
  \path[name path=line one] (#1) -- (#2);
  \path[name path=line two] (#1) -- (#3);
  \path[%
  name intersections={of=line one and circle, by={inter one}},
  name intersections={of=line two and circle, by={inter two}}
  ] (inter one) -- (inter two) coordinate[pos=.5] (middle);
  % put mark
  \node at ($(#1)!#5!(middle)$) {#6};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=below left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below right:$x$] (X) at (2,0);
\coordinate[label=above left:$y$] (Y) at (-3,5);

\draw[thick] (X) -- (A) -- (Y);

\markangle{A}{X}{Y}{7mm}{5mm}{$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your automated name of the angle is really smart! I will definitely use it in other occasions, thanks! However I don't understand the `coordinate(m)`in the clipping path. Is it necessary to name the point `#3`?

Comment: @sylcha the `coordinate(m)` in the clipping path was just a trace of an old test. I deleted it.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm getting an error "I do not know the path named 'circle'." Could that be because the "name path" is inside a scope? or some other issue? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT I modified the code.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that makes sense. Works great!

Answer (score 7):

I have developped 2 macros that I think can help you:

```
\newcommand{\Angulo}[7]{
\draw[#1]
    let \p1=($(#3) - (#4)$), \p2=($(#5) - (#4)$),
    \n{aIni}={atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \n{aFin}={atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{aMed}={0.5*\n{aIni}+0.5*\n{aFin}}
    in ($(#4)!#2 * \longU!(#3)$) arc (\n{aIni}:\n{aFin}:#2 * \longU)
    node at ($(#4) + (\n{aMed}:#2 * \longU)$) [#6] {#7};
}

\newcommand{\AnguloC}[7]{
\draw[#1]
    let \p1=($(#3) - (#4)$), \p2=($(#5) - (#4)$),
    \n{aIni}={atan2(\x1,\y1)},
    \n{aFin}={360+atan2(\x2,\y2)},
    \n{aMed}={0.5*\n{aIni}+0.5*\n{aFin}}
    in ($(#4)!#2 * \longU!(#3)$) arc (\n{aIni}:\n{aFin}:#2 * \longU)
    node at ($(#4) + (\n{aMed}:#2 * \longU)$) [#6] {#7};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%      Parameters:
%      \Angulo{drawing style}{radius}{starting point}{center point}{ending point}{text style}{text};
%      You can use coordinates or node names as points.

  \coordinate (nodeCenter) at (0,0);
  \Angulo{blue,->}{1}{10,0}{nodeCenter}{0,10}{above right}{$\alpha$};
  \AnguloC{red,<-}{1}{0,10}{nodeCenter}{10,0}{above right}{$\alpha - 360$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: what is `\longU`?