# How to draw arc in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to create this image, square and angle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle)

How do I draw an arc between lines OA and OB to indicate an angle?

```
\begin{figure}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3.8cm, circle] at (0,2) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.3,2) {};
\draw (0,2) -- (1.3,2);
\draw (0,2) -- (0.8,2.56);
\draw (0,2) -- (0.8,1.44);
\draw (0,2) -- (0,2.95);
\draw (0-0.1,2.5) node{$a$};
\draw(1.3,2)--(1.770,2.6);
\draw (1.4,2.3) node{$r$};
\draw (0-0.1,2) node{$O$};
\draw (0.8-0.1,2.56) node{$A$};
\draw (0.8-0.1,1.44) node{$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38818/best-way-to-denote-an-angle-in-tikz

Comment: I would also suggest some other changes as well to the code: Use `\coordinate (A) at (0.8,2.56);` to define a coordinate then you can use `(A)` in the code instead of `(0.8,2.56)`. This will make things easier to read. For instance: `\draw (O) -- (A);` were `(O)` is the coordinate for the origin (`(0,2)` in your case).  You can add nodes as part of the line `\draw (O) -- (Top) node [midway, left] {$a$}` where `(Top)` is `(0,2.95)`. Instead of defining new coordinates for nodes, use relative positioning to place them `\node [above] at (A) {$A$}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3.8cm, circle] at (0,2) {};
\node [draw, thick, minimum size=3cm, circle] at (1.3,2) {};
\draw (0,2) -- (1.3,2);
\draw (0,2) -- (0.8,2.56);
\draw (0,2) -- (0.8,1.44);
\draw (0,2) -- (0,2.95);
\draw (0-0.1,2.5) node{$a$};
\draw(1.3,2)--(1.770,2.6);
\draw (1.4,2.3) node{$r$};
\draw (0-0.1,2) node{$O$};
\draw (0.8-0.1,2.56) node{$A$};
\draw (0.8-0.1,1.44) node{$B$};
% This is the angle: Take that part of circle which comes inside this rectangle
\path[clip]  (0,1.86) -- (0.4,1.86) -- (0.4,2.14) -- (0,2.14) -- cycle;
% The circle itself
\node [draw, blue,  thick, minimum size=1cm, circle] at (0,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]