# What causes the presence of unnecessary white space?

Tags: pstricks

What causes the presence of unnecessary white space in the following figure? The box and the circle should have the same center.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](2,2)
    \rput(1,1){\psDefBoxNodes{A}{\pscirclebox{Circle}}}%
    \psframe(A:bl)(A:tr)%
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I write only "Cir" the space doesn't appear; if I write "Circ" there it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is a trailing space in an internal macro. Use http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex

[image]

Example for internal node names, needs current pst-eucl/pst-node from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\pstGeonode[CurveType=polygon](0,0){A}(3,3){B}(5,0){C}
\pstMarkAngle*[fillcolor=red]{A}{B}{C}{$\theta$}
\psdot(! N-A.x N-B.y )
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested `\pnode(2,1){B}\psdot(!B.x B.y)` and it works. Did you enable the shorten `<nodename>.x` instead of `N-<nodename>.x`?

Comment: no, too many problems. The new version also needs a `saveNodeCoords` option setting. There are problems with the xelatex driver and at the moment I don't know why

Comment: How about `<nodename>.X` (with uppercase X) instead of `<nodename>.x` (with lowercase x)? Is it possible?

Comment: it doesn't hurt to write `N-A.x` ...

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I think the update should be put in my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74554/9467).

Comment: `\pstMarkAngle*[linecolor=red]` (consistent convention) or `\pstMarkAngle*[fillcolor=red]` (inconsistent convention)?

Comment: setting the linecolor makes no sense, it is given by the lines of the polygon

Comment: Usually the starred version means that `fillstyle=solid`, `fillcolor=linecolor`, `linewidth=0pt`.

Comment: usually, but not in this case ...