# Help with drawing a triangle in using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a triangle using TikZ.  I managed to get it completed, but now I'm having trouble with getting the node to go into the body of the triangle.  I've only been using TikZ for a couple of days so this basic exercise has taken much longer than I care to admit.

How would I put the node within the body?

Although this does in fact draw a triangle, would you consider it properly done?  Is there a better way?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \draw[gray] ++(150:2.3) -- (0,0); %hypotenuse
        \draw[teal] ++(180:2) -- (0,0); %adjacent
        \draw[orange] (-2,1.15) -- (-2,0); %opposite

        \draw[thin] (-0.5,0.25) arc (150:180:0.5) 
            node[left] {\small $30^\circ$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: In order to plot the angle nicely and generally, you can use this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20864/412

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Processing the original code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[gray] ++(150:2.3) -- (0,0); %hypotenuse
\draw[teal] ++(180:2) -- (0,0); %adjacent
\draw[orange] (-2,1.15) -- (-2,0); %opposite

\draw[thin] (-0.5,0.25) arc (150:180:0.5) 
  node[left] {\small $30^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and zooming the resulting object, reveals two additional problems: the arc doesn't touch the hypotenuse and the hypotenuse and the shorter cathetus don't intersect:

[image]

Both problems are due basically to the same reason: manual calculation of coordinates.

To solve the problem with the arc, I would suggest you to use clipping and an additional node to draw the circle; in this way, you solve two problems: the arc is correctly drawn in an automated way (no need to guess angles as in the other answers) and you gain finer control over the label position:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] ++(150:2.3) -- (0,0); %hypotenuse
\draw[teal] ++(180:2) -- (0,0); %adjacent
\draw[orange] (-2,1.15) -- (-2,0); %opposite
\path[clip] (0,0) -- (-2,0) -- (-2,1.15) -- cycle;
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=40pt] at (0,0) (circ) {};
\node[font=\footnotesize,left] at (circ.160) {$30^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's still one other detail to improve: the hypotenuse and the opposite cathetus not intersecting. This can be solved by using the `intersections` library to automatically do the calculation of the intersection between the prolongations of the opposite cathetus and the hypotenuse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% place coordinates at the two initial vertices 
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (-2,0);

% automatically calculate the third vertex
\path[name path=line 1] (-2,0) -- (-2,2);
\path[name path=line 2] (0,0) -- (150:2.4);
\path [name intersections={of=line 1 and line 2, by={c}}];

% draw the lines
\draw[gray] (a) -- (c); %hypotenuse
\draw[teal] (a) -- (b); %adjacent
\draw[orange] (b) -- (c); %opposite

% draw the arc clipping a circle against the triangle and place the label
\path[clip] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=40pt] at (0,0) (circ) {};
\node[font=\footnotesize,left] at (circ.160) {$30^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As Sigur points out, you can use `above left` for placement. Also, I would suggest you to use `scale` option for sizing the contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray] ++(150:2.3) -- (0,0); %hypotenuse
        \draw[teal] ++(180:2) -- (0,0); %adjacent
        \draw[orange] (-2,1.15) -- (-2,0); %opposite

        \draw[thin] (-0.45,0.255) arc (149:180:0.5)
            node[ above left, scale=.7] { $30^\circ$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `scale=` was a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Use the option `node[above left]`