# Triangle with text

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me draw a equilateral triangle with numbers 1, 2, 3 at each interior angle of it? Also I need to equate a letter with that triangle; namely F = graph. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you've got, showing what you've tried. Even if it doesn't work properly it will encourage people to help you by giving them a place to start. Questions which just ask people to draw something for you are not really reasonable questions on this site even though you may get lucky and find somebody wants the exercise!

Comment: @cfr is talking about a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You can click on that link if you want some suggestions on how to prepare an MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Perhaps the might help get you started: [equilateral triangle in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88638/equilateral-triangle-in-tikz), [Help with drawing a triangle in using tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79350/help-with-drawing-a-triangle-in-using-tikz).

Answer (score 8):

Without any fancy techniques:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (2cm,0);
\coordinate (c) at (60:2cm);
\node[above left = 0.65cm and 0cm of a] {$F=$};   %% change distances suitably
%
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\path[clip] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=0.4cm] at (a) {};
\node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt] at (30:0.3cm) {$1$};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=0.4cm] at (b) (circa) {}
node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt,above left = 0.1cm and 0.2cm of b]  {$2$};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=0.4cm] at (c) (circa) {} 
node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt,below = 0.25cm of c] {$3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adopting the code from [Torbjorn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88640/11232):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        name=s,
        shape border rotate=0,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=3,        
        node distance=2cm,
        minimum height=4em
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[buffer,label={left:$F=\,$}]{};
\clip (s.corner 1) -- (s.corner 2) -- (s.corner 3) --cycle;
\draw (s.corner 1) circle (0.2cm) node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt,below = 0.25cm of s.corner 1] {$3$};
\draw (s.corner 2) circle (0.2cm) node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt,,above right = 0.1cm and 0.2cm of s.corner 2] {$1$};
\draw (s.corner 3) circle (0.2cm) node[font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt,,above left = 0.1cm and 0.2cm of s.corner 3] {$2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps...

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
F=\tikz[scale=.625,baseline=0pt]{
  \clip[preaction=draw] (-30:1) -- (90:1) -- (210:1) -- cycle;
  \draw\foreach \i [count=\j] in {90,210,-30}{ 
    (\i:1) circle [radius=.25] (\i:.875) node [anchor=\i,font=\tiny] {\j}};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
F=\tikz[scale=.625, baseline=0pt, inner sep=1pt]
    \draw  (-30:1) -- (90:1) -- (210:1) -- cycle
      \foreach \i [count=\j] in {90,210,-30}{ [shift={(\i:1)}, rotate=\i+150] 
        (.25,0) arc (0:60:.25) node [midway, anchor=\i, font=\tiny] {\j}};
\end{document}
```

Which produces (roughly) the same image as above.

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=.0+.1}{11}{%
\begin{pspicture}[LabelSep=.7,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none,CurveType=polygon](-.8,0)(3,3)
    \pstGeonode{A}(3,0){B}([nodesep=3,angle=-60]{A}B){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{B}{A}{C}{1}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{2}
    \pstMarkAngle{A}{C}{B}{3}
    \ncline[offset=15pt,linestyle=none]{A}{C}\ncput[npos=\n]{$F=$}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]