# Label an intersection with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following piece of code and I would like to add two things:

1. Add a label to the red dot i.e., the intersection of the line segments. Unfortunately, just a ${...}$ does not seem to work.
2. I want to draw an arrow from the vector a to the line segment showing that the vector is orthogonal to it.

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw (-1,3) coordinate (a_1) -- (3,0) coordinate (a_2);
\draw (-1,2.7) coordinate (b_1) -- (3.5,1) coordinate (b_2);
\coordinate (a) at (intersection of a_1--a_2 and b_1--b_2);    
\fill[red] (a) circle (1pt);
\tikzAngleOfLine(a_1)(a_2){\angle};
\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3) node[midway,above=0.1cm] {$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For 1), use something like `\node[label=below:$r$] at (a) {};`. For 2), how should that desired arrow be? (an arrow in the shape of an arc or something else?).

Comment: It should be something like the red arrow as in the accepted answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/label-angle-with-tikz

Comment: ooopss. Edited :)

Comment: Also, your suggestion for the label doesn't seem to output anything

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use a `\node` and its `label` key.
2. You can use the `angles` library and its `angle` pic.

The result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw (-1,3) coordinate (a_1) -- (3,0) coordinate (a_2);
\draw (-1,2.7) coordinate (b_1) -- (3.5,1) coordinate (b_2);
\coordinate (a) at (intersection of a_1--a_2 and b_1--b_2);    
\fill[red] (a) circle (1pt);
\node[label=below:$r$] at (a) {};
\tikzAngleOfLine(a_1)(a_2){\angle};
\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3)   
  node[midway,above=0.1cm] {$a$};
\coordinate (aux) at  ([shift={(\angle+90:20pt)}]a_2); 
\draw[<->,>=latex,red] pic[draw=red,angle radius=8pt]{angle = aux--a_2--a};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using the quotes library to place a value for the angle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\newcommand{\tikzAngleOfLine}{\tikz@AngleOfLine}
\def\tikz@AngleOfLine(#1)(#2)#3{%
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{%
\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{%
\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw (-1,3) coordinate (a_1) -- (3,0) coordinate (a_2);
\draw (-1,2.7) coordinate (b_1) -- (3.5,1) coordinate (b_2);
\coordinate (a) at (intersection of a_1--a_2 and b_1--b_2);    
\fill[red] (a) circle (1pt);
\node[label=below:$r$] at (a) {};
\tikzAngleOfLine(a_1)(a_2){\angle};
\draw[black,->] (a_2) -- ++ (\angle+90:0.3)   
  node[midway,above=0.1cm] {$a$};
\coordinate (aux) at  ([shift={(\angle+90:20pt)}]a_2); 
\draw[<->,>=latex,red] pic["{\tiny$90$}",draw=red,angle radius=8pt]{angle = aux--a_2--a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A zoomed in image of the arrow:

[image]

Comment: Is the angles library in place by default or should I install it?

Comment: @SotirisKal. It comes with the latest PGF release (PGF version 3.0).